# Change quarkus hazelcast cluster member ip

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, quarkus

is it possible to change quarkus.hazelcast-client.cluster-members=hazelcast:5701 to 127.0.0.1 but in kubernetes (not in application.properties)? For example in ConfigMap?

My configmap looks like this:

```
hazelcast.yaml: |-
  hazelcast:
    network:
      join:
        multicast:
          enabled: false
        kubernetes:
          enabled: true
          namespace: dev-1
          service-port: 5701
```

And I'm using hazelcast as sidecar container for my application.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but [every configuration property in quarkus is bound to an environment variable](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#environment-variables). So we could set a environment variable of `QUARKUS_HAZELCAST-CLIENT_CLUSTER-MEMBERS=localhost:5701` for the pod.

Comment: Which container image are you exactly using?

Answer (score 0):

For Hazelcast configuration, you can override properties [in different ways](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/configuration/overriding-configuration-settings.html):

- Use a System property
- Use an environment variable
- Provide a different configuration file

However, your question relates to Quarkus and not Hazelcast. Quarkus also offers a couple of [configuration override techniques](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference):

- System properties
- Environment variables
- .env file in the current working directory
- Quarkus Application configuration file in `$PWD/config/application.properties`
- Quarkus Application configuration file `application.properties` in classpath
- MicroProfile Config configuration file

In this regard, @Turing85 comment is correct.